# how to extract portion of string in RegEx

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I have a string: `Standard delivery in 5 business days`

I want to extract: `5 business days` from this string.

I wrote regex: `(/[0-9]/*)`

But it does not works.
Thanks.

Comment: Your * is outside where the modifiers go. That's my first hint. Maybe you wanted `/\d.*/` - but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\d.*$`, you can match digit and everything that follows it.

```
>>> import re
>>> matched = re.search(r'\d.*', "Standard delivery in 5 business days")
>>> matched
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000001E88578>
>>> matched.group()
'5 business days'
```

Comment: The $ is unnecessary.

Comment: In that +1, way to copy me! Just kidding. Seriously, +1 for being correct.

Answer (score 0):

`(/[0-9]/*)` matches a forward slash, a number between 0-9, another forward slash, then a greedy search.

There are no forward slashes in your regular expression, so remove them:

```
>>> import re
>>> print re.search(r'([0-9].*?$)', "Standard delivery in 5 business days").group(0)
5 business days
```

We need the `.*?` here to match the rest of the characters.